# Eclipse plugin for finding java classes that DOES NOT implement a given interface

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have grown tired of tomcat telling me it has problems with one or more classes that can not be deserialized when loading persistent session. So I wonder if anyone out there knows about a plugin for eclipse, or a stand-alone tool that can find all classes in my project / a given folder that DOES NOT implement Serializable and give me a list of them.

Comment: Please don't downvote before you know what the question is about or if you simply don't know of such a tool. I am sick and tired of people downvoting for no reason. Maybe SO should show who the downvoter is? That would probably prevent some of the meaningless downvotes...

Comment: I feel your pain Lars, sorry I do not have a solution, but maybe you could use AOP?

Comment: Bad idea: the JDK has about 300000 classes that are not deserializable.

Comment: I was not talking about the JDK classes, only the ones I have introduces into the system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) tool has a number of rules for bugs related to serialization; see [the list of bug descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html).  There is also an [Eclipse plugin](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/eclipse.html) for FindBugs.

Some related stuff:

- There is an [Inspection](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/80/help/inspections.jsp) in the YourKit memory profiler that will find objects that are declared as `Serializable` but have non-serializable fields:

  (That is more pertinent to your problems than classes that don't implement `Serializable`.)
- There is a Java runtime option [described here](http://sabob.blogspot.com.au/2008/02/httpsession-attribute-serialization.html) to get more information about the cause of a "not serializable" exception.

Comment: Thank you. This made life a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, just use grep on your src directory.

Fancy answer, use an annotation processor to generate custom Eclipse warnings, transform source, and other magic.  Good article:

http://java.dzone.com/news/using-java-6-processors